# How do you set a default input text format per content type?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes, input-formats

I want to be able to set a different default input text format per content type and per content field.

For example, the format type choices might be "*Plain text*" and "*Rich text editor*" and in some cases I want the format to default to "*Rich text editor*" but keep "*Plain text*" as a choice in the dropdown. I know that I can change the order of the text formats to make "*Rich text editor*" the first choice, but this method changes all of them, that's not what I want to do.

Answer (score 9):

In the absence of a stable release of [Better Formats](http://drupal.org/project/better_formats) module, you can create a custom module to do this for specific content types or fields.

[Create a module](http://drupal.org/node/1074360) (modulename.info and modulename.module, inside a folder 'modulename'). Example:
default_text_format.module:

```
<?php
/**
* Implements hook_element_info_alter().
*
* Sets the text format processor to a custom callback function.
* This code is taken from the Better Formats module.
*/
function default_text_format_element_info_alter(&$type) {
  if (isset($type['text_format']['#process'])) {
    foreach ($type['text_format']['#process'] as &$callback) {
      if ($callback === 'filter_process_format') {
        $callback = 'default_text_format_filter_process_format';
      }
    }
  }
}

/**
* Callback for MODULENAME_element_info_alter().
*/
function default_text_format_filter_process_format($element) {
  $element = filter_process_format($element);
  // Change input format to "Filtered HTML" for body fields of article nodes
  if ($element['#bundle'] == 'article' && $element['#field_name'] == 'body') {
    $element['format']['format']['#default_value'] = 'filtered_html';
  }
  return $element;
}
```

And default_text_format.info:

```
name = Default text format
description = Adapt the module code to set a default format for a content type.
package = Custom modules
core = "7.x"
```

Put these files in a folder 'default_text_format' in sites/all/modules/custom.

Change bundle name as appropriate for your content type. And you can substitute 'body' with your own 'field_contenttype_fieldname'. (After [this comment](http://drupal.org/node/1003262#comment-4879140) / better_formats code.)

Comment: I tried this and altered it to work so it worked for me.    ` foreach ($type['text_format']['#process'] as $key => $callback) {
      if ($key == 'filter_process_format') {
        $type['text_format']['#process'][] = 'MODULE_NAME_default_text_formats_filter_process_format';
      }`

Comment: I can confirm @awm's solution. The original answer does not work for me also, because it overrides the default callback. awm's solution fixes that by adding the callback, instead of overriding.

Comment: Update - I take back my last comment. The original answer does work and is preferred. It didn't work for me because I had Better Formats module installed, which has overridden my callback. Ideally, you want to disable it before adding this function. Now - in the case where you do add a second callback to the array (as the comment above me suggests), callback #1 will be processed first, thus altering data before it hits your callback.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Better Formats](http://drupal.org/project/better_formats) module:

Better formats is a module to add more flexibility to Drupal's core input format system.
It will allow you to set the default format per content type and much more.

Comment: Thanks, looks promising but I'm using D7 on a production website so I'm not at this time going to use this module because It's still in development.

Answer (score 3):

I just bumped into this problem myself, but I didn't want to use a beta module (Better Formats), and I had to extend the functionality and automate it, so that such settings are not hardcoded, but set from the back-office.

So I did the following:

- I added a setting on the Edit Settings form of the field that I need the default text format for
- I used the code provided the above and modified it slightly so that it gets sets the default text format as saved in the settings of the field
- I used Features to export the content type so that I have my settings preserved in code

**Field Edit Settings part**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FIELD_UI_FIELD_EDIT_FORM_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_form_field_ui_field_edit_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form['#field']['type'] == 'text_long') {
    $instance = $form['#instance'];
    // Fieldset for Default Formats settings.
    $filters = filter_formats();
    $options = array('_none' => t('None'));
    foreach ($filters as $key => $filter) {
      $options[$key] = $filter->name;
    }
    $form['instance']['settings']['default_filter'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('Default Filter Settings'),
      '#collapsible' => FALSE,
      '#collapsed' => FALSE,
    );
    $form['instance']['settings']['default_filter']['wysiwyg_profile'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Select a default format for this field'),
      '#description' => t('The selected text format will influence the button and plugin configuration of WYSIWYG.'),
      '#default_value' => isset($instance['settings']['default_filter']['wysiwyg_profile'])
          ? $instance['settings']['default_filter']['wysiwyg_profile'] : '_none',
      '#options' => $options,
    );
  }
}
```

So this part of the code should evident enough...it adds a fieldset and adds a select list in it, which is populated by the WYSIWYG profiles existing on your site. Those WYSIWYG profiles are tied to the text formats, so when someone selects a text format/filter, it actually selects the profile that is configured.

Now the 2nd part is the same code as provided above by another user, and which is taken from the Better Formats module.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_element_info_alter().
 *
 * Sets the text format processor to a custom callback function.
 * This code is taken from the Better Formats module.
 */
function MY_MODULE_element_info_alter(&$type) {
  if (isset($type['text_format']['#process'])) {
    foreach ($type['text_format']['#process'] as &$callback) {
      if ($callback === 'filter_process_format') {
        $callback = 'MY_MODULE_filter_process_format';
      }
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Callback for MY_MODULE_element_info_alter().
 *
 * Alters the default text format of fields.
 */
function MY_MODULE_filter_process_format($element) {
  $element = filter_process_format($element);
  // Configuration array that specifies the fields that need to be altered.
  $field_info = field_info_instance($element['#entity_type'],
                                    $element['#field_name'], 
                                    $element['#bundle']);
  // Change input format to configured value.
  if (isset($field_info['settings']['default_filter']['wysiwyg_profile']) && $field_info['settings']['default_filter']['wysiwyg_profile'] != '_none') {
    $element['format']['format']['#default_value'] = $field_info['settings']['default_filter']['wysiwyg_profile'];
  }
  return $element;
}
```

So the settings are saved, therefore Features Export is possible or whatever method you use to save your settings.

I hope this helps anyone else who encountered this problem!